# Iptables With CPanel/WHM Blocking Traffic

Tags: web-server, iptables, centos5

I have script for an iptables configuration that seems to be loading successfully.  However, I then cannot access my website on port 80 or CPanel and WHM on ports 2087 and 2083 (previously possible).  I would appreciate help in debugging the issue with my HTTP traffic.

Note for below: In the output below, does the target acctboth in Chain INPUT with policy DROP mean that any rules in acctboth are dropped?  Can I blanket change this, since acctboth are supposed to be accepted?

I'm on a CentOS 5 installation with CPanel/WHM.  After installing my iptables configuration, saving, and restarting, this is what `iptables -nL` outputs (note Chain acctboth was present before my modifications, as it was set by CPanel/WHM):

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 0 
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 11 
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 4 
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3 
acctboth   all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:21 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:20 
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:20 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2083 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2087 
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
acctboth   all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain acctboth (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
           tcp  --  [MY_IP_1]            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_1]           tcp spt:80 
           tcp  --  [MY_IP_1]            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_1]           tcp spt:25 
           tcp  --  [MY_IP_1]            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110 
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_1]           tcp spt:110 
           icmp --  [MY_IP_1]            0.0.0.0/0           
           icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_1]           
           tcp  --  [MY_IP_1]            0.0.0.0/0           
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_1]           
           udp  --  [MY_IP_1]            0.0.0.0/0           
           udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_1]           
           all  --  [MY_IP_1]            0.0.0.0/0           
           all  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_1]           
           tcp  --  [MY_IP_2]            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_2]           tcp spt:80 
           tcp  --  [MY_IP_2]            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_2]           tcp spt:25 
           tcp  --  [MY_IP_2]            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110 
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_2]           tcp spt:110 
           icmp --  [MY_IP_2]            0.0.0.0/0           
           icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_2]           
           tcp  --  [MY_IP_2]            0.0.0.0/0           
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_2]           
           udp  --  [MY_IP_2]            0.0.0.0/0           
           udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_2]           
           all  --  [MY_IP_2]            0.0.0.0/0           
           all  --  0.0.0.0/0            [MY_IP_2]           
           all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: its much easier install CSF, so that you can set allow/block ports and ips. Also on installation of CSF, a plugin will be created on whm, which makes it easier to manage from front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its much easier install CSF, so that you can set allow/block ports and ips. Also on installation of CSF, a plugin will be created on whm, which makes it easier to manage from front end

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll take a look at it and will return here with my results.

Comment: CSF is much easier to deal with.  Thanks.

Here: [ConfigServer Security & Firewall](http://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html)

Comment: absolutely. It has much more features. Please go through /etc/csf/csf.conf to get an idea of its capabilities.